# How to allow any Content-Type in S3 policy conditions?

Tags: amazon-s3

My conditions look like this:

```
"conditions":[
            { "bucket": bucket },
            ["starts-with", "$key", key],
            { "acl": acl },
            ["content-length-range", 1, filesize],
            ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "*/*"]
        ]
```

I want to allow ANY `Content-Type`. Tried `*/*`, `*` but it is always rejected. Also tried to not specify any conditions for content type but then it rejects with "not allowed extra field"...

Comment: Did you try an empty string? `["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""]`

Comment: Thanks it works! If you will add answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty string as an argument to the `starts-with` operator allows any value to match.

```
["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""]
```

> To configure the POST policy to allow any content within a form field, use starts-with with an empty value ("")
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html#sigv4-ConditionMatching

Comment: how you convert your  pdf or other format data  in buffer or what you  pass in body  while uploading

Comment: @su_sundariya the request body is standard `multipart/form-data`.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html